# Excel Date preservation

Tags: excel, date

I have four columns Date (A), OrderID (B), Description (C), Amount (D)
I want to create a formular on the date column such that, if orderID is entered say today(21/12/2023), todays date (21/12/2023) will reflect on the Date column, if five days later, i have another order, and i enter an orderID, the date (30/12/2023) will show on that row but the first date (21/12/2023) will not change, and it keeps on going, meaning the present date shows but preserves other date that was generated in previous days.

The formular i have used is working but anytime i try to update a table by entering new orderID, the entire date column will change to the present date. Here is the formular below.

=IF(B2 <> "", TEXT(NOW(), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), "")

I need the previous dates to be preserved

Comment: Use VBA for this, not formulas..